# Using useRef to assign focus to an element that conditionally exists

Tags: reactjs, use-ref, react-forwardref

I am having some trouble trying to implement this functionality which creates an input field component upon clicking a button, and then assigning focus to the input field as well. I am getting an error saying that inputRef.current is undefined, and am not sure how to proceed.

```
export default function Post(props) {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  const [commentsToggle, setCommentsToggle] = React.useState(false);

  function commentClickHandler() {
    setCommentsToggle((prev) => !prev);
    inputRef.current.focus();
}

return (
<div className="post">
  <div className="postAuthor">
    <Avatar
      {...stringAvatar(`${props.post.author.username}`)}
      alt={`${props.post.author.username}'s Avatar`}
      src="./placeholder.jpg"
      variant="rounded"
      style={avatarStyle}
    >
      {props.post.author.username[0].toUpperCase()}
    </Avatar>
    <b>{props.post.author.username}</b> posted:
  </div>
  <p className="postContent">{props.post.content}</p>
  <p className="postDate">{props.post.formatted_date}</p>
  <span className="postButtonContainer">
    <IconButton className="starsButton" onClick={starClickHandler}>
      {props.post.stars.includes(userInfo.userID) ? (
        <StarIcon />
      ) : (
        <StarBorderIcon />
      )}
      {props.post.stars.length}
    </IconButton>
    <Tooltip title="Add a comment." placement="right">
      <IconButton className="commentsButton" onClick={commentClickHandler}>
        {commentsToggle ? <ChatBubbleIcon /> : <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon />}
        {props.post.comments.length}
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  </span>
  <hr></hr>
  <div>
    <CommentList comments={props.post.comments}></CommentList>
    {commentsToggle ? (
      <NewCommentInput
        ref={inputRef}
        targetPostURL={props.post.url}
        getUserData={props.getUserData}
        setCommentsToggle={setCommentsToggle}
      ></NewCommentInput>
    ) : null}
  </div>
</div>
);
}
```

The above is the code from my parent component, which will conditionally render the child component (the input) that I want to receive focus. Below is this input component:

```
const NewCommentInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
return (
<form className="commentInput" onSubmit={commentSubmitHandler}>
  <TextField
    ref={ref}
    multiline
    fullWidth
    size="small"
    name="comment"
    placeholder="comment on this post..."
    value={commentState.content}
    onChange={commentChangeHandler}
  ></TextField>
  <Button variant="outlined" onClick={commentSubmitHandler}>
    Comment
  </Button>
</form>
);
});
```

How can I solve inputRef.current being undefined when I click the button that create the component that has the ref?

Comment: The problem is that the input field is not rendered yet, and therefore does not have a current element stored in its ref, when the `commentClickHandler` gets called. What you could try is, to defer the focus method call in a `useEffect` within the `NewCommentInput` component to give itself focus once it's mounted. The `useEffect` would run after the initial render

Comment: Just to elaborate: state updates do not have immediate effect, so setting the comments toggle flag to true will just schedule a re-render request, but all code running in the current render cycle is still looking at old state that is not updated, yet. The ref is still empty. `useEffect` is generally the best place for dealing with component and HTML element refs. It runs after the component was rendered, so `ref.current` will be populated

Comment: @tiguchi thank you so much for the detailed and insightful response. I was able to solve my issue with the advice you provided.

Comment: Another good options in these kinds of scenarios is to use a callback ref. You pass a function that will receive the ref element when it's mounted, and then call `focus` on it from there.